# Do something when div content changes to a given value

Tags: jquery

I am Trying to do something when the content of a DIV changes to an "O", but it does not seem to work for me.

My code looks like below. Any Ideas on how I can solve this problem :

```
jQuery('.select2-chosen').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(event)
{
    var newText = $(this).text();
    alert(newText); 
    if($('.select2-chosen:contains("O")').length === 1)
    {
        alert(newText);
    }
});
```

Comment: How the content of the div change ?

Comment: When you select a value from the dropdown which is dynamically populated. not really a dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/n4n5Y/307/)**.

Why not just using `change()` event since `select-2` will triggers the standard DOM event, so try :

```
$('#SPECIFIC_ID').on('change', function() {
____^^^^^^^^^^^  //Don't forget to change the id with yours

    var selected_text = $('option:selected', this).text();

    if( selected_text == "O" ){
         alert('the selected value is O');
    }
})
```

Hope this helps.